# Java create a connection via socket without configure the router to forward the port

Tags: java, sockets, portforwarding, tunneling, port80

I made a Server via Sockets with the port 5902.
The client can connect, but only if I forward the port on the router.
Is there a (simple) way (with a library?) to create a tunnel through port 80? 
Because somebody told me I should do this but I don't know how to.

P.S. I don't want that a library creates the 5902 socket and for example writes all recieved data in a file or in the console, I want (if it's possible) that I have my Socket and get all data there.

Comment: A tunnel from where to where?

Comment: A tunnel from port 80 to port 5902

Comment: Why not just create your socket with port 80?

Comment: because port 80 is already used (i think by browsers)

Comment: browsers don't use outgoing port 80

Comment: But whatfor is port 80 default opened?

Comment: what do you mean? default opened where?

Comment: default forwarded by the router

Comment: I don't know why your router is configured this way. Try to start your server when it's bound to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the third-part library,just like netty,you can read the example [netty proxy](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy) which can filter all over data from a port and then you can send them to target port or discard them.